# avoiding sensitive info in openstack config files

Tags: sqlalchemy, configuration-files, openstack

Is there a way to avoid storing passwords in openstack config files (e.g. sqlalchemy connection strings with db passwords)
I'd like to version-control my openstack config files using git (with the possibility of sharing them)

Is there a way to sort of "include" private info from other files, e.g. sql connection string from a "gitignored " txt file?

NB. I copied my question over from ask.openstack hoping for more answers than none.

Comment: the config files tend to use gflags in python so you may want to look into that.

Comment: pastes are different though.

Comment: I resorted to using ansible which allows use of "variable placeholders" for installation specific or sensitive info in config file templates.

Comment: chef edbs would be better as far as cfm solutions go.